# How can I make a list of n + 1 values with constant increment between two numbers?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for a quick way to make a list of n + 1 values with constant increment between two numbers.

For example, if the input is:

```
min = 0
max = 10
n = 8
```

I want the output to be:

```
[0, 0.125, 0.250, 0.375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.75, 0.875, 1.0]
```

Currently, I'm using a function that looks like this:

```
def const_increment_list(min, max, n):
    increment = (max - min) / n
    return [min + i * increment for i in range(n + 1)]
```

Is this possible to do in a single line?  My current method feels too verbose.

**Edit:**

You can use NumPy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [numpy.linspace](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) if you don't mind the dependency.

```
linspace(min, max, n+1)
```

Comment: FWIW, in your original notation it would be linspace(min,max,n+1) (not n)

Comment: Thanks Rory, I added the example line in an edit and just edited it again for correctness.